# Calendar.MONDAY from Java to PHP

Tags: java, php, calendar

I needed to find the equivalent to all these Java Calendar statements to PHP, can someone help me to figure out this?

```
int periodPayDay = Calendar.MONDAY;

Calendar todaysDate = Calendar.getInstance();
workingCal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
workingCal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no one to one solution.
Because I don't know what you want to do, but you could do the following:

```
 $payDay = "Monday"; // set the string for the payday

 $date = date(l); //get the string for today
```

There is no Calendar object (maybe a library has one)
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native equivalent to the Java Calendar object in PHP.  Your best best is to look at the PHP date function(s): http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

The first two lines do have PHP counterparts and could be implemented as follows:

```
$periodPayDay = 1;  //int periodPayDay = Calendar.MONDAY;
$todaysDate = time();  //Calendar todaysDate = Calendar.getInstance();
```

I'm not sure how to implement the last two lines in PHP.  As far as I can tell, the week is always assumed to run from Sunday (0) to Saturday (6) and there is no equivalent to the `getActualMaximum()` function.

Would you be willing to rephrase what you are looking to do in a language-agnostic way?  There might be a way to do what you want in PHP, but not in a directly translatable way from Java.

Comment: Currently i made the test with one java IDE and the result for todaysDate was: `java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1426108957646,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Regina",offset=-21600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=54,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=11,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=11,DAY_OF_YEAR=70,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=3,HOUR_OF_DAY=15,MINUTE=22,SECOND=37,MILLISECOND=646,ZONE_OFFSET=-21600000,DST_OFFSET=0]` maybe left the tmezone

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Date_Calc** class which has many useful methods for working with dates

> There you can configure DATE_CALC_BEGIN_WEEKDAY

[Download Date_Calc from here](http://www.phpinsider.com/php/code/Date_Calc/)